# CaptionPanel -> CaptionLayoutPanel

Tags: gwt

I want to use the CaptionPanel inside a Layout Panel (DockLayoutPanel) .

The problem is that there is no CaptionLayoutPanel(like SimpleLayoutPanel) implementation and therefore if I want to use
this panel inside a Layout Panel, all childs will loose the resize events because the "resize-chain" is broken through  the CaptionPanel.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: `CaptionPanel` compiles to an HTML `<fieldset>`. Just stick a `CaptionPanel` as the widget of a `SimplePanel`, add the `SimplePanel` to your `DockLayoutPanel`, and use CSS to give the `CaptionPanel` 100% width and 100% height so it'll resize to its `SimplePanel` parent.

Comment: @ Roddy of the Frozen Peas  This will not solve the problem. He is concerned that children of CaptionPanel will not get resize because CaptionPanel does not provide size to its children.

Comment: The problem is not to have the 100% width and 100% height for the CaptionPanel. If I add the CaptionPanel to an SimpleLayoutPanel in your example, the CaptionPanel has automatically 100% width and 100% height.  The problem are the childs of CaptionPanel. If I add an Datagrid to the CaptionPanel, then it will not get automatically all the available space because CaptionPanel has broke the resize chain( not implemented the interface RequiresResize & ProvidesResize).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend `CaptionPanel` and implement the `ProvidesResize` and `RequiresResize` interfaces

```
CustomCaptionPanel extends CaptionPanel implements RequiresResize,ProvidesResize {

    public void onResize() {
        if (getContentWidget() instanceof RequiresResize) { 
            ((RequiresResize) getContentWidget()).onResize(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your example ümit.
two problems:
* getChildren() is not existing
* I changed your onResize method into following:

    public void onResize() {     
        if (getWidget() instanceof RequiresResize) { 
            ((RequiresResize) getWidget()).onResize(); 
        } 
    }
But the problem is, that this example is not working.

Comment: There is no getChildren() for CaptionPanel. I edited the answer with getContentWidget() instead. It should show up when my edit is approved.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin: Thanks for the edit. It was apparently rejected. I manually edited my post

Comment: Great! It's nearly perfect. I just have to set the childs height manually to 98% (normally it's not necessary for Layout Panels) to fit in the caption panel.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is not to use CaptionPanel.

If you want children to respond to resize events, add a layer to your LayoutPanel that will hold a caption (Label), and another layer that will contain a child widget that you want to respond to resize. You can style these widgets any way you like (e.g. a Label can look like a tab or a panel with some background and rounded corners, etc.)

An alternative solution is style your CaptionPanel as Roddy of the Frozen Peas suggested, and then add a ResizeHandler to your window. When triggered, you can set the size of a child widget to

```
myChildWidget.setSize(myCaptionPanel.getOffsetWidth() + "px", myCaptionPanel.getOffsetHeight() + "px");
```

Comment: thanks for your hint andrei. can you please give me an example for your first answer. how can I style the layoutpanel to have the captionpanel effect?

Comment: I was able to successfull implement an example with your first advice.
Thx a lot!